# what's the C# equivalent of string$ from basic

Tags: c#, string

And is there an elegant linqy way to do it?

What I want to do is create string of given length with made of up multiples of another string up to that length

So for length - 9 and input string "xxx" I get "xxxxxxxxx" (ie length 9)

for a non integral multiple then I'd like to truncate the line.

I can do this using loops and a StringBuilder easily but I'm looking to see if the language can express this idea easily.

(FYI I'm making easter maths homework for my son)

Comment: I don't think that's what string$ did is it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing simple and elegant - you have to basically code this yourself.

You can construct a string with a number of repeated characters, but ot repeated strings,
i.e.

```
string s = new string("#", 6);    // s = "######"
```

To do this with strings, you would need a loop to concatenate them, and the easest would then be to use substring to truncate to the desired final length - along the lines of:

```
string FillString(string text, int count)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i <= count / text.Length; i++)
        s.Add(text);

    return(s.ToString().Substring(count));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using `Enumerable.Repeat`.

```
const int TargetLength = 10;

string pattern = "xxx";

int repeatCount = TargetLength / pattern.Length + 1;

string result = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(pattern, repeatCount).ToArray());

result = result.Substring(0, TargetLength);

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(result.Length);
```

Comment: Enumerable.Repeat. That's the thing I was looking for thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My Linqy (;)) solution would be to create an extension method. Linq is language integrated *query*, so why the abuse? Im pretty sure it's possible with the select statement of linq since you can create new (anonymous) objects, but why...?

Comment: I actually wanted a solution to the creation of the strings rather than how to use it in the I think I should have said using the some cool stuff in the System.Linq namespace. You are right in that linq is query.